# kdb/q -- how do I select by customized time list?

Tags: kdb

I know I can `select by sym, time.second from table` to select by seconds or use `xbar` for some other fixed time intervals

But they are more or less uniformed time intervals. How do I supplied a completely customized list of times into the select by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use binr to accomplish this

```
q)tab:([]t:.z.d+10000?.z.n)
q)/ create custom bins ensuring in ascending time order for binr to work correctly 
q)tl:.z.d+09:30 10:45 15:32
q)/ x binr y - will return the index of first item in x which is ≥y 
q)/ we then index back into our tl with result 
q)select count i by tl tl binr t from tab 
t                            | x   
-----------------------------| --
2019.03.31D09:30:00.000000000| 6443
2019.03.31D10:45:00.000000000| 807 
2019.03.31D15:32:00.000000000| 2750
```

Comment: Note that bin uses binary search which assumes that the list of times are sorted and won't give expected results if they are not.  Try adding 12:00 onto the end of `tl` for example